# Solr Docker: Cannot load Core from filesystem

Tags: docker, solr

I would like to start solr in a docker container, loading an existing core from filesystem, which is stored in `/tools/solr_cores/metadata`

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM solr:8.11.2
VOLUME ["/tools/solr_cores"]

ENTRYPOINT solr start -s /tools/solr_cores/ -p 8984; sleep infinity
```

This is my `run_docker.sh:`

```
docker build -t mysolr .
docker run --name "mysolr" --restart always -d -p 8984:8984 -v /tools/solr_cores:/tools/solr_cores mysolr
```

When loading the solr web interface, it says:

```
metadata: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: /tools/solr_cores/metadata/data/index/write.lock
```

I also removed the `write.lock` file from filesystem before executing run_docker.sh, but the error is still the same.

Comment: i think there is a high probability that the **ENTRYPOINT command** is the reason. Can you try if the command run normally without the docker?

Comment: @lemoana When I run the command without any docker container, it works fine. Then, the core is loaded correctly.

Comment: I have found out, that I do not have write access to the mounted volume /tools/solr_cores in the docker container. However, this write access is needed to use the solr core correctly. How can I get write access to a mounted volume in a docker container?

Comment: Add this `-u 8983:8983` to your `docker run ...` command. (8983 is uid of user solr)

Comment: Even without this option, the docker user has the id 8983:8983 (this is caused by the "FROM solr" statement). The problem here is that the directory /tools/solr_cores is owned by the user 12738:7017 and the solr usr doesnt have permissions to write there. Is there any way to get permissions in the docker container for directories owned by id 8983 AND directories owned by 12738?